# Why does bytes(5) return b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' instead of b'\x05'?

Tags: python, byte

I'm converting int to bytes using this command in python:

```
a = 5
b = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
```

but when I print `b` I get this value:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

what is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: What did you expect to be output instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters 5 in bytes representation! this is zero!

Comment: You don't mean binary do you? In which case you're looking for `bin(5)` which produces `0b101`

Comment: @FarzinHooshmand: that's not really clear. Do you bean `b'5'`? Or 5 in binary notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`bytes()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) points to the [`bytearray()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray), which states:

> The optional *source* parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> - *[....]*
> - If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.

You asked for a `bytes()` object of size 5, initialised to null bytes.

You probably want to turn `a` into a string first:

```
bytes(str(a), 'utf-8')
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> bytes(str(a), 'utf-8')
b'5'
```

If you wanted to have the byte value `5` (so the [`ENQ` ASCII control code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) or whatever else you might want it to mean) you'll need to put it `a` in a list:

```
bytes([a])
```

(no need to provide an encoding then):

```
>>> bytes([a])
b'\x05'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a byte array of length 5.

To get the binary represenation of the number 5 you can use bin()

```
bin(5)
0b101
```